# (Cascading Dropdown) Not able to edit newform.aspx in sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I tried [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using) but in step 5, I am not able to edit the newform.aspx.I am not able to add the `spservices` code there, it seems like the codes there can not be edited.

Comment: Check if you have opened page in `Advanced Mode` or not. Advanced Mode button can be found in ribbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click "Advanced Mode" button under "Editing" category in the ribbon

Answer (score 0):

Create a new newform and try there. The default one works a little differently.
After changing you can make the changed forms The default new/edit form.

Alternatively when in the browser go to the list menu and find the form edit buttons. Click the form you want to edit and add a content editor webpart to the bottom. Either link to the JavaScript in a file or enter it there manually.